# 301's using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Setting up my .htaccess file with 301's.
All working fine for most redirects apart from the following ...

```
RewriteRule bluewidget /blue-widget/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule bluewidget/folder2 /blue-widget/folder2/page2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule bluewidget/folder3 /blue-widget/folder3/page3 [R=301,L]
```

If i goto ww.mysite.com/bluewidget - redirects to ww.mysite.com/blue-widget (which is correct)

But ...

If i goto `ww.mysite.com/bluewidget/folder2` - this redirects to `ww.mysite.com/blue-widget` (should goto `ww.mysite.com/blue-widget/folder2/page2`)
or
`ww.mysite.com/bluewidget/folder3` - this redirects to `ww.mysite.com/blue-widget` (should goto `ww.mysite.com/blue-widget/folder3/page3`)

What am i doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^bluewidget$          blue-widget/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^bluewidget/folder2$  blue-widget/folder2/page2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^bluewidget/folder3$  blue-widget/folder3/page3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The `$` marks the end of the request url (which has to be overwritten).